# Implicitly including optional dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a project A which has a dependency X. Dependency X has an optional dependency Y which doens't get included in A by default. Is there a way to include Y in my POM without explicitly including it? In Ivy they have a way to essentailly say include all optional dependencies of X, does Maven have a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

According to the Maven docs:

> Optional dependencies - If project Y
>   depends on project Z, the owner of
>   project Y can mark project Z as an
>   optional dependency, using the
>   "optional" element. When project X
>   depends on project Y, X will depend
>   only on Y and not on Y's optional
>   dependency Z. **The owner of project X
>   may then explicitly add a dependency
>   on Z, at her option**. (It may be
>   helpful to think of optional
>   dependencies as **"excluded by
>   default."**)

Comment: This doesn't help you very much since you need to include the version of Z, so if Y changes, X needs to change his pom.